# using fabricjs to get selected group on canvas and then change text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to add curved text on my canvas . This Example works Al right . i am trying to add curved text whenever user type text in text-area it should check if any one canvas object is selected if selected then text for the selected object should get change otherwise new object should be added on canvas .

check the fiddle , http://jsfiddle.net/NHs8t/7/

Below code i have written to check if any object on canvas is selected or not ?? but canvas.getActiveGroup() is not working any help ???

Jquery Code::

```
$('.text').change(function() {

        var act = canvas.getActiveGroup();

            var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
         if(!obj)
         {
            console.log('object not Selected');
         }else
         {
            console.log('Object  selected');
         }
         if (!canvas.getActiveGroup()) 
         {
            console.log('if part executed--object not selected');

            curvedText[cur] = new CurvedText(canvas, {});
            curvedText[cur].center();
            curvedText[cur].setText($(this).val());
            cur++;


        } else {
            console.log('Else part executed-object selected');
            act.setText($(this).val());
            $("<li id='item_li" + i + "' class='item_list'> " + $(this).val() + " <div class='updown' style='text-align:right;'> [ <a id='down_link" + i + "' class='down'>Down</a> ] [<a id='close_link" + i + "' class='close'>Close</a>] </div></li>").appendTo($("#items_list"));
        }

    });
```

Comment: try using the new curvedText https://github.com/EffEPi/fabric.curvedText, then you can use it as a normal Text and the selection will work.  The fiddle that you have uses a Group already and might not full work with other fabric functionalities.

Comment: Hey I am using spectrum plugin to set fill colour of text but changes only reflect after changing spacing or radius .. what would be the problem  I am using obj.set('fill', color)

Comment: Seems like a bug ... can you post it to the github repos ?

Comment: Hey, I'm also getting the same bug. please suggest a solution for this.